# my home dir is emptied by windows?

Tags: windows-xp, home-directory, wipe

My notebook (xp) has recently broke down, and I moved its HDD to my desktop (xp) as a slave drive, to access my data. To work with more or less the same environment as before, I set the home dir of the user on the desktop to the directory on the notebook's HDD that used to be my home. I have the same username on the desktop as the one on the laptop. Now I am shocked to see that the specified directory has been completely emptied. Is it a normal behavoiur of windows ? Are my data deleted or possibly moved to another place ? They aren't in recycle bin for sure.

Thanks.

Comment: Just because they were the same username does not mean they would use the same user profile ( they won't ).  Are you sure the actual user profile you were using is now empty?

Comment: Make sure you have the required [permissions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308419/en-us) to actually view the folder content.